# Conditions of a signed lease

Tags: tenant, residential-lease, new-mexico

I've been renting a house for about 7 years now. For the first year we had a signed lease. After that, its never been renewed. I just pay rent every month. No problems.
My question ... do the condition of that signed lease apply now?
For example, the lease contained a late fee of $50 if the rent was more than 4 days late.
Would that still apply?

Comment: You may find terms in the lease that specify that those conditions within the lease are continued on a month-to-month basis, which would include the late fee.

Comment: Good point. So then, if not specified in the original lease, it does not carry over?

Comment: I'd be surprised if it's correct that the the has never been renewed. The standard language would be that at the end of the initial term, the lease automatically renews, if only on a month-to-month basis.

Comment: @Al the question says it *is* in the original lease. It is 99% certain that all relevant conditions apply when it rolls on. Why wouldn't the $50 still apply? Can you imagine the lessor saying "Pay as late as you like?"

Comment: Its a matter of contract law I suppose. The lease was signed for 1 year, say 5/1/2015-4/30/2016, so why would a contract that expired on that date still be valid.

Comment: @AlLelopath What we're telling you is the contract likely didn't expire. It likely says in it that the contract continues with the lease period being month-to-month. The initial lease period and the overall contract validity period are two separate things. By not turning in the keys and continuing to pay rent, you're extending the contract.

Comment: ok thanks, I will read the lease closely for my own edification

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are likely now a holdover tenant, as you have stated that you continue to pay your original monthly rental payments. Check original lease and investigate what happens at end of lease.

P.S. As your original question does not state a rent increase, may want to pay the $50.

Comment: Really... if 7 years and no rent increase... don't draw attention to yourself.

Comment: This is purely hypothetical. I pay my rent automagically. The late fee was just an example. There are probably other conditions I could have cited